scanmatic python connection using udsoncan via passthru
I'm working on a project where I need to read and write various data in VAG cars using udsoncan. Often, I need to read large amounts of data from different blocks. I want to use multiple devices for this. I have an Abrites device that autoconfigures itself using only the drivers, and I haven't had any problems with it.
The essence of the question is how to configure a Scanmatik device for reading data. Both devices work through the PassThru protocol, but Scanmatik does not self-configure. There is a library, VW_Flash, where the connection is implemented, but I lack the experience to "adapt" this solution to my project.
Here are my paths to the drivers:
ABRITES_PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ABRITES software for ID 17111B\\PassThru\\AbrPT32.dll"
SCANMATIK_PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Scanmatik\\smj2534.dll"

And here is my implementation of the connection via Abrites using udsoncan:
class J2534CANConnection(J2534Connection):
    def __init__(self, windll: str, rxid: int, txid: int, name: Optional[str] = None, debug: bool = False, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(windll, rxid, txid, name, debug, *args, **kwargs)
        txFlags = TxStatusFlag.ISO15765_CAN_ID_11.value
        self.interface = J2534(windll=windll, rxid=rxid, txid=txid, txFlags=txFlags)
        self.protocol = Protocol_ID.CAN

call:
WINDLL = os.getenv('ABRITES_PATH')
J2534CANConnection(
    windll=WINDLL,
    rxid=int(os.getenv('GATEWAY_RXID'), 16),
    txid=int(os.getenv('GATEWAY_TXID'), 16),
)

I get an error when substituting Scanmatik drivers and equipment:
2024-10-29 23:37:58,257 - app.config - INFO - DASH connection
2024-10-29 23:37:58,328 - Connection - INFO - J2534 FirmwareVersion: b'', dllVersoin: b'', apiVersion b''
2024-10-29 23:37:58,328 - Connection - ERROR - J2534 PassThruConnect: Error_ID.ERR_INVALID_DEVICE_ID b'ERR_INVALID_DEVICE_ID'
2024-10-29 23:37:58,328 - Connection - ERROR - J2534 PassThruIoctl SET_CONFIG: Error_ID.ERR_INVALID_CHANNEL_ID b'ERR_INVALID_CHANNEL_ID'
2024-10-29 23:37:58,328 - Connection - ERROR - J2534 PassThruIoctl CLEAR_MSG_FILTERS: Error_ID.ERR_INVALID_CHANNEL_ID b'ERR_INVALID_CHANNEL_ID'
2024-10-29 23:37:58,328 - Connection - ERROR - J2534 PassThruStartMsgFilter: Error_ID.ERR_INVALID_CHANNEL_ID b'ERR_INVALID_CHANNEL_ID'
2024-10-29 23:37:58,328 - Connection - ERROR - J2534 PassThruIoctl CLEAR_RX_BUFFER: Error_ID.ERR_INVALID_CHANNEL_ID b'ERR_INVALID_CHANNEL_ID'
2024-10-29 23:37:58,328 - Connection - ERROR - J2534 PassThruIoctl CLEAR_TX_BUFFER: Error_ID.ERR_INVALID_CHANNEL_ID b'ERR_INVALID_CHANNEL_ID'
2024-10-29 23:37:58,328 - app.config - INFO - connection target = <app.services.connection_type.J2534CANConnection 

